# display ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this python script using class where it gets the student name, student number, student course and its grades.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.courses = {}

    def displayStudent(self):
        return 'Student Name: ' + self.name + '\n' + 'Student Number: ' + str(self.number)

    def addGrade(self, course, grade):
        self.courses[course] = grade

    def displayGPA(self):
    gpa = 0.0
    try:
        if self.courses.keys() != 0.0:
            for course in self.courses.keys():
                gpa = gpa + self.courses[course]
            return 'GPA of student ' + self.name + ' is ' + str(gpa / len(self.courses))

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('oops')


    def displayCourses(self):
        return [k for k in self.courses.keys() if self.courses[k] > 0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create first student object and add grades for each class
    student1 = Student('John', '013454900')
    student1.addGrade('uli101', 1.0)
    student1.addGrade('ops235', 2.0)
    student1.addGrade('ops435', 3.0)

    # Create second student object and add grades for each class
    student2 = Student('Jessica', '123456')
    student2.addGrade('ipc144', 4.0)
    student2.addGrade('cpp244', 3.5)
    student2.addGrade('cpp344', 0.0)

    # Display information for student1 object
    print(student1.displayStudent())
    print(student1.displayGPA())
    print(student1.displayCourses())

    # Display information for student2 object
    print(student2.displayStudent())
    print(student2.displayGPA())
    print(student2.displayCourses())
```

After executing, it successfully displays this output:

```
Student Name: John
Student Number: 013454900
GPA of student John is 2.0
['ops435', 'ops235', 'uli101']
Student Name: Jessica
Student Number: 123456
GPA of student Jessica is 2.5
['ipc144', 'cpp244']
```

What I want to do is, If no courses are added under `addGrade(self, course, grade):` function, It should display a ZeroDivisionError.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: What is this line supposed to do: `if self.courses.keys() != 0.0:`?!

Comment: Have you considered *not catching* the ZeroDivisionError?

Comment: You're already getting a ZeroDivisionError in the case you're talking about (because you're dividing by zero), but you're catching it.

Answer (score 3):

You can throw any error with:

```
raise ErrorYouWantHere("Some Message")
```

in your case

```
raise ZeroDivisionError("No course added")
```

But the question is, why do you want a `ZeroDivisionError`. It's best to follow the intention of the errors, and `ZeroDivisionError` is meant to be thrown when you try dividing something by zero.

Maybe you want a `ValueError` instead?

Comment: Division by zero is a reasonable behaviour here. The OP is trying to calculate the mean of a list of values, i.e., `sum(values) / len(values)`. If he wants to raise the error, he shouldn't catch it in the first place. If he wants to do something before the error is raised, then he should use the catch-raise you seem to be suggesting.